# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't turns on

Tags: 12.04

my computer has Ubuntu 12.04, and it was super slow, so I restarted it, and I couldn't turn on anymore. Before, I think that the same thing happened, I asked my computer teacher, he said that it was because that my computer was full, he put a flash disk in it, and I don't know what he did, 10 minutes later, I got my computer reset, it was back to factory version, I lost everything. So my question is, how do I fix the problem now? I have no idea what my teacher did... Thanks VERY much to the person that helps!!! I need to use my computer so bad(I'm on phone right now so.)

This has already been solved, so I don't need anymore answers:) All I did was keep on pressing Fn and F9 and it turned on normaly :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** "Some error" can quite easily be fixed by doing "something". So if you don't know what the teacher did, we don't either and we can't help you...  **:-(**

Comment: Oh...okay... :'-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot your computer using a Linux disc or a flash drive. Once booted, you can access the data and create backup. Increase the size of your primary partition. If you have an explicit swap  partition, edit it and increase its size. Reinstall the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you give me a link for booting my computer or something please? And how do I boot...? And how do I increase the size?   P.S. I got the laptop from school, and I can't do some stuff, like, I don't even know the password... Everyone gets the exact same laptop in 7th grade, so, and I asked my teacher if I can update to 14.04, he said that he's not sure, because the school doesn't wants us the ruin the computers I guess...

Comment: How to boot from USB: http://lifehacker.com/5991848/how-to-boot-from-a-cd-or-usb-drive-on-any-pc; Installing USB from flash drive: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyways! Maybe I can use that later, but my friend told me to press down Fn and keep pressing F9 and it worked out!!! Yay it was so easy! I could really use your help someday! Thanks!